# node.js cloning eventemitter object

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling

I have a game

```
game = {
  turn: 5,
  players : []
}

game.events = new events.emitter()
game.events.on('attack', handleAttack)
```

I need to clone (deep) the gamestate exactly to another object so that I can run simulations of the game for AI. How would I clone the event object?

Comment: Are you opposed to using a library? Lodash offers a great method called `_.cloneDeep` that will do a deep clone of an object

Comment: Is state also involved in the events? If the events are stateless then you can clone your objects' properties but they can all share a common events.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie state is involved yes.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'm using lodash but it doesn't work on functions.

Comment: The thing is, why is state being stored in your function? Can that be refactored so that the function is stateless, then this becomes a trivial problem.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie You're right that's probably the best way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, do not include state in the functions and that makes copying the functions unnecessary.

Here is a fairly trivial example.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Game {
  constructor(name, turn) {
    this.turn  = turn;
    this.name = name;
    this.events = new EventEmitter();
    this.events.on('attack', () => {
      console.log(`${this.name} is attacking`);
    })
  }

  clone(){
    const copy = new Game(this.name, this.turn);
    //clone the other properties
    return copy;
  }

}


const g1 = new Game("One", 5);
const g2 = new Game("Two", 4);

g1.events.emit('attack');
g2.events.emit('attack');

const g3 = g1.clone();
g3.events.emit('attack');
```

You have to pay careful attention to cloning the properties themselves but notice that g3 is just a copy of g1. Hope this helps.